# Unable to change Identity to 'username' in Codeigniter Ion Auth?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I have installed ion auth and everything is up and functional. The only problem I have is I want to change the login to use the visitors username instead of e-mail. I change the CONFIG option in the ion_auth.php config file and it still doesnt work. Is there an extra step Im missing??

ion_auth config

```
/**
 * A database column which is used to
 * login with.
 **/
$config['identity']            = 'username';
```

login() in the controller

```
//log the user in
function login()
{
    $this->data['title'] = "Login";

    //validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail Address', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
    { //check to see if the user is logging in
        //check for "remember me"
        $remember = (bool) $this->input->post('remember');

        if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember))
        { //if the login is successful
            //redirect them back to the home page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
            redirect($this->config->item('base_url'), 'refresh');
        }
        else
        { //if the login was un-successful
            //redirect them back to the login page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
            redirect('auth/login', 'refresh'); //use redirects instead of loading views for compatibility with MY_Controller libraries
        }
    }
    else
    {  //the user is not logging in so display the login page
        //set the flash data error message if there is one
        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');

        $this->data['email'] = array('name' => 'email',
            'id' => 'email',
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('email'),
        );
        $this->data['password'] = array('name' => 'password',
            'id' => 'password',
            'type' => 'password',
        );

        $this->load->view('auth/login', $this->data);
    }
}
```

login() model

```
public function login($identity, $password, $remember=FALSE)
{
    if (empty($identity) || empty($password) || !$this->identity_check($identity))
    {
    return FALSE;
    }

    $query = $this->db->select($this->identity_column.', id, password, group_id')
              ->where($this->identity_column, $identity)
              ->where('active', 1)
              ->where($this->ion_auth->_extra_where)
              ->limit(1)
              ->get($this->tables['users']);

    $result = $query->row();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
    $password = $this->hash_password_db($identity, $password);

    if ($result->password === $password)
    {
        $this->update_last_login($result->id);

        $group_row = $this->db->select('name')->where('id', $result->group_id)->get($this->tables['groups'])->row();

        $session_data = array(
                $this->identity_column => $result->{$this->identity_column},
                'id'                   => $result->id, //kept for backwards compatibility
                'user_id'              => $result->id, //everyone likes to overwrite id so we'll use user_id
                'group_id'             => $result->group_id,
                'group'                => $group_row->name
                 );

        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);

        if ($remember && $this->config->item('remember_users', 'ion_auth'))
        {
        $this->remember_user($result->id);
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: has it worked with email? post the code of the option, post the code of your use.

Comment: Yes it does work with email. It is a default installation with the default administrator row add via mysql. I have also created a couple dummy accounts too. All I am doing is changing it to 'username' and attempting to login to the default login screen at /auth/login. Just provides me an login error. The only thing I changed was the config identity option. Am I supposed to create my own login controller based on that change?

Comment: See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626292/can-i-set-ion-auth-to-login-by-username-or-email/24776598#24776598

Answer (score 1):

Why are you still processing email in the controller (instead of username)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your controller since it is still grabbing email from POST and using it to try to login.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an index in the users table of username column